# Postfix / Dovecot multiple mailboxes directories creation issue

Tags: postfix, dovecot

It's been 3 days I'm trying to configure Postfix with Dovecot with virtual mailboxes.

My virtual mailboxes are stored here :

```
la -la /var/mail

drwxrwsr-x 17 postfix postfix 4096 Jan 17 22:55 vhosts
```

Inside the vhosts, I will take an example (there are 16 domains):

```
ls -la /var/mail/vhosts 

drwxrwsr-x  4 postfix postfix 4096 Jan 17 23:20 thebarcodemaster.com
```

And inside this folder I got two virtual mailboxes

```
ls -la /var/mail/vhosts/thebarcodemaster.com/
drwxrwsr-x  5 info@thebarcodemaster.com postfix 4096 Jan 17 22:56 info
drwxrwsr-x  5 test@thebarcodemaster.com postfix 4096 Jan 17 23:21 test
```

Here's an extract of my /etc/postfix/vmailbox :

```
info@thebarcodemaster.com thebarcodemaster.com/info
test@thebarcodemaster.com thebarcodemaster.com/test
```

Here's an extract of my /etc/postfix/main.cf :

```
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

When I want to send a mail to info for exemple, Postfix return me this error :

```
tail /var/log/mail.log

[...]
Jan 18 08:12:22 9963C6E postfix/virtual[10442]: 2B316210F8: to=<info@thebarcodemaster.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.05, delays=0.04/0/0/0, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (delivery failed to mailbox /var/mail/vhosts/thebarcodemaster.com/info/new: unable to create lock file /var/mail/vhosts/thebarcodemaster.com/info/new.lock: Permission denied)
```

I worked on it since 3 days, and I'm kinda lost.
It seems that Postfix has the issue and not Dovecot, I can connect to my accounts (info, etc...) on Outlook.

Is someone have some tips ? Thanks a lot